# Create divs and load each with a file based on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So I have the below code which is supposed to get a directory of html files, take each one, and load the contents into a new div with the class ".module". My directory and file names are retrieved correctly, a new div is created correctly, but the problem is that only one div is created and it is only loaded with the content from the last file in the directory. Can't seem to figure out why!

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url: 'modules/',
           dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
           success: function(data) 
              {
                 $(data).each
                    (function() 
                       {
                             var filename = this;
                             console.log(filename);
                          $('#wrapper').html('<div class="module editable moveable deletable">');
                          $('#wrapper').append('</div>');
                          $('.module:last-of-type').load("modules/"+ filename);
                       });
              },
              error: function(error){
                 console.log('failed with error ' + error.status);
              }
        });
     });
```

Comment: What if you change `$('#wrapper').html('<div class="module editable moveable deletable">'); $('#wrapper').append('</div>');` to `$('#wrapper').append('<div class="module editable moveable deletable"></div>');`?

Comment: Does the console show the list of all the filenames?

Comment: Exactly; you're overwriting the entire content of `#wrapper` each time. And you don't need to append a closing tag.

Comment: Yes, the console is returning the filenames correctly. This seems to be some issue of just getting the jQuery to propogate the divs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `.each()` with this:

```
$(data).each(function() {
  var filename = this;
  console.log(filename);
  $('#wrapper').append($("<div>").addClass("module editable moveable deletable"));
  $('.module:last-of-type').load("modules/" + filename);
});
```

Comment: That didn't quite do it, although I did change my ".html" to ".load".

I've done this which does create my divs and puts the classes in them, but it's also adding the classes to all my other parent divs in the DOM.


`$('#wrapper').append("<div>");
                              $('#wrapper').append("</div>");
                              $('div:last-of-type').addClass('module editable moveable deletable');
                              // $('.module:last-of-type').load("modules/"+ filename);`